# WPF, MVVM, Entity Framework with Oracle DB. can not set a nullable field to null value

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, oracle11g, nullable

I have mapped a Oracle Table into my entity framework schema. this table contains a nullable number(2) field (PROP). This is the mapping fragment generated by Framework

```
    Public Property PROP() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int16)
    Get
        Return _PROP
    End Get
    Set
        OnPROPChanging(value)
        ReportPropertyChanging("PROP")
        _PROP = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, "PROP")
        ReportPropertyChanged("PROP")
        OnPROPChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

When I try to set PROP = Nothing, the null value is replaced by 0, and this may cause data inconsistency.
How can I force PROP field to accept the Oracle NULL value?

Comment: You are going to have to abandon SetValidValue.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485567(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Reason being that the definition (in the case of a decimal) is 

protected internal static decimal SetValidValue(
 decimal value,
 string propertyName
)

which does NOT support nullable values.

Comment: There is an override that takes a nullable input.  Make sure which override is being used, I suspect it is not the nullable version.

Comment: John, that code fragment is auto-generated by EF 5. is there some setting I have to change? Anymore, debugging the application, I noticed that the "value" passed to Set is already 0

Comment: Not so much a setting, but are you using code like 

'decimal x = 0m;'
'Prop = x;'

Comment: no, simply i use something like myRec.PROP = propValue (which is Nothing). but inspecting myRec I see that PROP is set to 0, even if i use a DefaultValue in mapping file

Comment: How is propValue declared?

Comment: my variable was declared as Nullable(Of Int16). after several attempts, I noticed that the mapped db PROP was of type Nullable(Of Short), even if was built as Nullable(Of Int16). So I changed propValue to Nullable(Of Short), and now PROP accepts null value

Comment: Good deal :)  Glad it worked.  It's often the little things